# Get listbox item value whilst looping through array

Tags: arrays, vba, listbox

I have a 2D array with dimensions (0 to 19, 0 to 7) and I have a listbox in which column 0 displays the values of Row 0 in the Array. In listbox column 3 (4th column) I have an RGB value with a comma delimiter e.g. 0,255,255. I have a function in a class where I am passing the array, and the listbox as parameters like so (point is a coordinate location but not relevant for this problem):

```
Set oText_LB1 = TextFromArray(Point, ArraysSorted(0), FrmMain.LB_Sheet1)
```

the function declaration is written as:

```
Private Function TextFromArray(Point As Point3d, ByRef CurrArray As Variant, ByVal LBox As ListBox)
```

The purpose of the TextFromArray function is to create text elements from the array values and some the listbox columns are being used to store text formatting values (colour/font/height & width sizes etc..). The Text elements are being created in a transposed format so i.e. the headers are to the left (stacked vertically) and the column values in the array are created horizontally from left to right. As such my array loop code is:

```
For C = LBound(CurrArray, 2) To UBound(CurrArray, 2)
    For R = LBound(CurrArray, 1) To UBound(CurrArray, 1)
```

As I begin each row, I want to get the value stored in the listbox column 3 so that all text elements are created with the correct colour e.g. For Array Row 0, get the listbox value of 0,3. I previously just passed the RGB value as a parameter to the TextFromArray function and everything worked fine but I am struggling how to use get the value. I've tried using:

```
For C = LBound(CurrArray, 2) To UBound(CurrArray, 2)
    For R = LBound(CurrArray, 1) To UBound(CurrArray, 1)
       sRGBVal = CStr(LBox.List(C, 3))
```

but this gives an invalid use of null error. I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction. Let me know if there is any information lack and I will provide additional code or images if necessary.

Thanks

Comment: Which line are you getting the error on?

Comment: The 3rd line with sRGBVal is where the error occurs. I need the array column value to correlate to the listbox row value and capture the item value in the listbox's column 3 for that row.

Comment: What is the value of C?  Also, how are you passing the listbox to the function?  If you stop the code and do in the immediate window:  ?LBox is nothing, are you getting confirmation that the object exists?

Comment: The value of C uses the array bounds of 0 to 7. The reference to the listbox is currently passed is shown in the first code sample in the original post. Could it be that problem is due to the code I've posted is written within a function in a class and passing the listbox reference as a parameter to a function in a class doesn't work like it does when the function exists in a module?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the function definition to pass the listbox as a generic object (do not declare byRef or byVal) like so:

```
    Private Function TextFromArray(Point As Point3d, ByRef CurrArray As Variant, _
                                   LBox As Object)
```

If that doesn't work, you might try passing the entire form instead of the listbox in the same manner and then just access the listbox from the form you passed.

Comment: Ok I just tried that but still same result. Not sure if its worth anything but when the error occurs, the LBox does contain information as can be seen in the locals window. This can be seen at http://i.imgur.com/nqAQ1n2.png .

Comment: Are you sure that your listbox is populated at the time that you are trying to access the rgb value from it?

Comment: I just had a hallelujah moment, though somewhat embarrassing at the same time. The form is indeed populated as can be seen at http://i.imgur.com/PGkeb1I.png. However upon reviewing the Go! button code, after the line which starts the class, the class requires a data point (left-click) to confirm where the origin of the text is created. The code continues and I discovered that it moves to the next line in the Go! button which is `unload me` which explains why object didn't exist!. I was under the impression I only had it hiding. Thanks for the suggestions which helped me solve my own mistake.